# Is 'feeble' used correctly in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

Sentence:"This belt is too feeble."

Google search shows it as an adjective, curious if it can be used in another way.

**Edit**: I mean to say the belt is weak.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.  Yes, ***feeble*** is an adjective, and that's how it is used in the sentence.  I don't see where any other way to use it comes into the picture.  Grammatically, the sentence is fine.  In terms of word choice, however, describing a belt as *feeble* strikes me a bit oddly.

Comment: @PellMel do you agree with my analysis of why "feeble" feels "odd", below?

Comment: @MaxWilliams, yes, pretty much.  I agree that *feeble* is not properly applied to mechanical strength in the sense of durability, resiliency, or toughness.  I think you hit the mark when you opposed *powerful*, but then rebounded a bit with a definition of that word that fails to account for, say, a powerful (/ strong / energetic) person.  There are some pretty subtle distinctions in this area, and in cowardly fashion I decided not to essay an explanation myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can't call a belt feeble, and the reason lies with the differing definitions of "weakness" and "strength": "strength" can refer to "mechanical strength", eg ie how hard something can be squashed, pulled, distorted etc before it breaks, or it can mean "powerful", which refers to "the strength of an action", like a "strong argument" or a "strong punch".

"Feeble" means "physically or mentally weak", and while a belt could be said to be "physically weak", *physically* in this sense is closer to "physiologically", ie a weakness of a biological organism: it really refers to the ability of the person (or animal, or robot for that matter) to *do something*, or the attempt itself. So it's talking about the "strength of an action" definition i describe above.

A belt has "mechanical strength", and so can be strong or weak in that sense, but it can't do anything (of it's own accord), and so it cannot have any *actions*, and so it can't be **feeble**.

A good "mechanical strength" equivalent of "feeble" is **flimsy**:  it would be wrong to call a person "flimsy" as this implies that it's easy to break them into pieces, which (we would hope) isn't what you are interested in doing to them.  But it makes sense to call a belt flimsy - it implies that it will break easily.

This distinction isn't explained in the dictionary, but I believe it to be valid nonetheless.

http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/feeble

EDIT - to answer your actual question, ie "can we use feeble as something other than an adjective", then, strictly speaking, no you can't.  But of course it's a free country etc.  Peter Jackson made a movie called "Meet the Feebles" but this was a pronoun (like The Muppets).

Answer (score 0):

The lovely thing about Modern English is it allows you to use a word in almost any way you like. Certainly, we feel 'feeble' belongs in the category we call adjectives. And in your sentence we would traditionally say feeble is functioning as an adjective, and as a complement. Or something like that.

But 'feeble' will happily work as a noun. We can talk about strong and the feeble. And I think this isn't really an ellipsis. I think feeble really is functioning as a noun.

And 'feeble' can be a verb. Granted, it's not common, but it's certainly grammatically possible. And to a native speaker, it wouldn't sound at all strange to hear me saying that after writing all the feebles, I am feebled out! And if we allow that the 'past participle' sounds OK, then I think we have to accept that feeble can be a verb.